# What is the best way to update state with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assuming I have a stateful variable as so `const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1,2,3]);` what is the preferred/best way to update state and why? From a technical level. I have encountered rendering cycle mismatch before and I got the solution shown to me but I want to understand why.

Option 1:

```
setNumbers(numbers.slice(1))
```

Option 2:

```
setNumbers(state => numbers.slice(1))
```

Option 3:

```
setNumbers(state => state.slice(1))
```

Which one of these is the "correct" way to go about it, especially to avoid unwanted render cycle mismatch between state being updated and UI showing updated state?

Comment: The **3rd option** this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGo3MVBFr1A&t=8s) describes useState and useEffect nicely.

Comment: Option 2 is definitely not the way to go, as callbacks are provided to setState only when state has to be updated based on previous state that is passed as the only argument to that function. If you're sure to use previous state, option 3 should be way to go IMO. React docs has some info on it in this section: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state

Comment: Shouldn't option 2 and 3 both have the same value of `numbers`? Why would I want to use option 3 to get previous value of state when numbers is already previous?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer option 3
As using the functional form of setNumbers with a callback that receives the previous state as an argument, like setNumbers(state => state.slice(1)), is a recommended approach in React when you need to update the state based on the previous state. It helps avoid potential issues with stale state values when multiple state updates occur in rapid succession.